# re sizing two dimensional array with average of elements shifted to smaller matrix in c

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

can any one help me re size divisible matrix in to smaller matrix with elements be calculated to the sum average  i,e like from 6x6 matrix  in to 2x3 matrix where the elements like average of r1c1,r1c2,r2c1,r2c2,r3c1,r3c2 shifted in to r1c1 of the 2x3 matrix.

Comment: Please correct your grammar. It's almost impossible to know what you want to know exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `array` points to the array, 'l,w' hold dimensions of original array, 'r,c' hold the dimensions of the smaller result array.

```
int rows = l/r; //# of rows of the window
int cols = w/c; //# of columns of the window
int num = rows*cols;//# of cells of the window
int result = new int[r][c];

for(int i=0;i<r;i++)//for each row in the result array
{
    for(int j=0;j<c;j++)//for each cell in the current row
    {
        result[i][j] = 0;//initialize the cell value
        for(int k=0;k<rows;k++)//for each row in the window
        {
            for(int z=0;z<cols;z++)//for each cell in the current row
            {
                result[i][j] += array[i*rows+k][j*cols+z];//add the value of each cell in the window to the corresponding result cell
            }
        }
        result[i][j] /= num;//divide by the number of cells in the window
    }
}
```

p.s. i didn't test this code, but it should work

Comment: you're welcome, I'm glad it helped. Can you please mark this answer as correct.

Comment: No it's not, that is the upvote button, and you don't have enough reputation yet. but you did mark it as the answer (the tick)- thanks-.